Bokeh - Trying to use Taptool and Tooltips to measure horizontal distance
Since the feature request to support measuring the distance between two points on a chart has been killed for insufficient interest, I'm thinking about how to do it with the existing mechanisms.
My idea is to:

Use the tap tool to collect the index of the first point (I'm really only interested in the horizontal distance)
Display the difference between that point to the current hover tool position

I think I see how to do most of this, but I'm wondering how to communicate the value collected by the tap to the hover tool.
Can this be done?
I've looked through documentation for the tap tool and the hover tool with custom formatting
